# Tensorflow/Keras local training 6x faster than distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I am training a Classifier (via RNN) in Tensorflow with tf.data api, tf.keras api and tf. estimator api. In local training i got a troughput of around 240 steps/sec, than i enter distributed mode with ParameterServer (due to proper TF_CONFIG) with 1 Worker (so 1 PS and 1 Chief = 1 Worker) i got around 40 steps/sec. If i add 1 Worker (now 2 Worker) i got around 50 steps/sec and so on. I tested this behavior at home (with multiple pc's) and in cluster (around 18 worker). Only with 18 worker i reached the speed i got at local training. I testet training with nfs,hdfs, changed os. Network cant be the problem because an other framework scaled pretty good.
Can someone please guide me on how to get better perfomance. I tried alot but didnt find a suitable solution.

### My Code

```py
data_pipeline = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(MODEL_DIR, DEFAULTS, header=False,field_delim=CSV_SEPARATOR) \
                        .shard(WORKER, WORKERINDEX) \
                        .map(lambda *a: tf.stack(a), num_parallel_calls=THREADS) \
                        .window(size=WINDOW_SIZE, shift=WINDOW_SHIFT, stride=WINDOW_STRIDE,drop_remainder=True) \
                        .flat_map(lambda b: b.batch(WINDOW_SIZE)) \
                        .map(lambda c: (c[:,:-1],tf.one_hot(tf.cast(c[-1][-1], tf.int32),2))) \
                        .batch(GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True) \
                        .repeat(REAPEAT_DATASET) \
                        .prefetch(PREFETCH)
```

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, batch_input_shape=(GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE, NR_FEATURES),activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=2), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(RNN_UNITS,stateful=True,activation=tf.keras.activations.tanh, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2),recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2),bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation= tf.keras.activations.softmax, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2), bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE), # AdamOptimizer
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(dtype=tf.float32),tf.keras.metrics.Recall(dtype=tf.float32),tf.keras.metrics.Precision(dtype=tf.float32,class_id=0),f1_score])
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, config=RUN_CONFIG, model_dir=LOG_DIR)
```

```
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL), steps=100,start_delay_secs=20,throttle_secs=1*60/6)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

```
cluster_spec_dict = {'ps': ['192.168.2.XXX:50012'],'chief': ["192.168.2.XXX:50014"],}
```

- Tensorflow version: 1.14
- dense / rnn units = 5
- batch_size=16
- window_size/sequence_length=16